# Strategey needed to tackle multi threaded perfomance problem

Tags: multithreading, performance, visual-studio-2022

My application runs a bunch of pipe-lined steps in different threads.

One thread is reading data from a TCP connection, grabs a handle (shared_pointer) to a buffer from a pool of buffers, and hands it off to the processing chain. The shared_pointer deleter returns the buffer to the buffer pool.

Each thread runs a loop:

- waiting for a buffer
- performing its processing step
- hand the buffer to the next thread in the pipeline.

The problem is that the application's processor load is progressively increasing (even after I've removed every part of the processing chain that does any work so we're just pushing a shared_pointer across a bunch of threads).

After instrumenting the code with a bunch of time stamping, I see that there is no part of the code that takes any longer over time. However the processor load keeps increasing and once one of the cores hits 100% then the time *between* one thread handing off a buffer and the next thread picking it up skyrockets until my buffers are not returned to the buffer pool in time and the TCP reading stalls waiting for an available buffer.

Most of the pipeline steps use classic producer/consumer queue/wait-condition logic. Some are implemented with Qt Signals/Slot - the QThreads fail faster but even removing these from the picture the problem persists.

My memory foot print is not growing.

So the questions:

- what can be causing the processor load to increase continuously?!
- how might I go about using the Visual Studio Performance profiler to track this?

  - is there a way I can see the start and end time of every function call in the stack across threads?